# How can I configure OpenBSD to automatically use one of many Wi-Fi SSIDs?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid, openbsd

In OpenBSD 6.0, with (for example) the [iwn(4)](http://man.openbsd.org/iwn.4) driver, I can automatically associate with an SSID and bring up the interface with DHCP by using the following `/etc/hostname.iwn0`:

```
nwid SSID
wpakey secretkey
dhcp
```

How can I configure my system so that it automatically uses one of several configured SSIDs depending on which one is in range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenBSD has got a [package named wpa_supplicant](http://ports.su/security/wpa_supplicant). It comes with an example configuration that is documented thoroughly and has reasonable defaults (see in directory `/usr/local/share/examples/wpa_supplicant` after installation of the package).

All you need to do is to insert a few network blocks describing your access points. They look like this:

```
network={
    ssid="simple"
    psk="very secret passphrase"
    priority=5
}
```

It is also advisable to look how to restrict ciphers (e.g. to use only WPA2). There are dozens of examples [listed  here](http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf).

`wpa_supplicant` runs as a daemon after you start it with:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wirelessinterface -c /path/to/wpa_supplicant.conf
```